# as3: Fullscreen Flash game without "This page is now full screen" notification in Chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, fullscreen

I'm working on a Flash game, and I have implemented a Fullscreen button. I notice that when I play it in Google Chrome and click on it to go into fullscreen mode, a message from the browser pops up that says, "This page is now full screen," with the choices "Dismiss" or "Exit Full Screen". This is in addition to the Flash message that asks if you want to allow or cancel fullscreen. I've played a few other Flash games with fullscreen buttons, and they all have the Flash message, but not the Chrome message. How can I stop the Chrome message from appearing?

Comment: Can you post the code that you used to enter in fullscreen mode?

Comment: stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;

Comment: I have experienced same warning with IE 11 and Edge. So it may not be totally related to a certain browser but a message from Flash to the browser engine.

Comment: Verify in Chrome if you have some domains set to allow fullscreen, this domains do not show the Chrome message: chrome://settings/contentExceptions#fullscreen